# Array overwritten after foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, overwrite

I'm trying to push objects containing elements from a sql result set into an array. My code is like:

```
$data = array();
$sql = "SELECT id,type,name,username FROM users";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { 
    $this->set_id($row['id']);
    $this->set_type($row['type']);
    $this->set_username($row['username']);
    $this->set_password($row['password']);

    $data[] = $this;
}
```

My resultset is correct but I get my array cells overwritten with values from the last recordset after the foreach loop ends. For example, if I have these results `{1,'type1','user','pass'}`, `{2,'type2','foo','bar'}`, when I print_r my `$data` array ouside of the loop, I get only the second resultset repeated twice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're updating a single instance of $this each time you loop, and then pointing each array element to the same $this.... if $this is your model, then you need a new instance for each array element

Answer (score 3):

Inside an instance method, `$this` always refers to the current class instance; at every loop iteration you modify the instance itself and then add it to `$data`; but at the point of assignment a copy is not made and a reference to the same instance is added instead.

In the end you have an array with the same object at each index.

You would need to create a new instance of the class you're in at every loop iteration:

```
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { 
    $obj = new self; // create new instance of ourselves

    $obj->set_id($row['id']);
    $obj->set_type($row['type']);
    $obj->set_username($row['username']);
    $obj->set_password($row['password']);

    $data[] = $obj;
}
```

This is a personal suggestion, but I would either move this code inside a static method or a separate class altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Objects don't work like that, `$this` is always the same object and you modify it in every iteration. You *could* use `$data[] = clone $this;` to create a new instance every time but this is bad class design and you would be better off to break your class into two separate classes.

A class should not have more than one responsibility, but yours acts as database gateway and domain model at one time.

Comment: Thanks fab, I solved this separating model and database tasks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `$this` is, it's a reference to some kind of object. So, when you update that object, all of the references saved in the array are still pointing to that same object. You have to define a new object in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating new `$this` object at the beginning of the iteration. In both iterations you are modifying the same object, and adding it twice to the array. When dealing with objects, those are passed by reference, meaning that you do not add a copy to the array, but add a reference to $this variable. Maybe you should add `$row` to the array instead, but you would still overwrite the data you save into `$this`.

You might also use `clone` keyword (see [manual](http://php.net/clone)) to save a copy of the object.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php